# ObjectAtIndex Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

Program crashes at the line with comments below. Not sure what's wrong. Any tips for a 1st time programmer?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
    //My program runs but then crashes at this line, I have no idea what's wrong with it though "reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"


    return cell;
}
```

*Some More Code (Not all of it though) As Requested*

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    users = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [users count];
}
```

**In .h file**

> @interface GIFUsersListViewController : UITableViewController {
>
> ```
> NSArray *users;
> NSMutableData *data;
> ```
>
> } @end

Comment: while you may *think* users is an Array the compiler error is telling you it's not. The compiler is correct.

Comment: Users is apparently in fact an NSDictionary, not what you were expecting. You should post the code where users was created.

Comment: Ok. I will post more code so it seems like this portion is ok ??- because this is where I get a green SIGARBT sign

Comment: Wait, I have users declared as an NSArray in .h file, but when I changed it to NSMutableDictionary i got an error on the same line for No visible interface for NSMUtableDictionary

Comment: Show the code where you create users.

Comment: looks like typo `NSMUtableDictionary` instead of `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: It was alright lol, that was just me making a typo on here

Comment: With JSON, you should check the class of what it returns, put a log right under the users = ... (it should be NSLog(@"%@",[users class]);

Comment: It says __NSCFDictionary   but I use an array in .h file???

Comment: Your problem is where you are setting users as JSONObjectWithData returns JSON data, not an NSArray.  Which it seems that this JSON data is actually an NSDictionary.

Comment: Ok, no surprise there, given your error message. You should just be able to remove the indexAtObject part. Just have [users objectForKey:...]

Comment: It is very strange  that you expect your users object (whatever type that is) is indexed by row, and then each user also has the row again as a key in that dictionary? Something seems wrong there. But start by figuring out users.

Comment: I changed 

 cell.textLabel.text = [[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];

to 

 cell.textLabel.text = [users objectForKey:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];

and 

NSArray *users;

to

NSMutableDictionary *users;

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post the solution so here it is in the comments^

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll get mutable dict by default (even I'm almost sure that you won't), you should pass `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option if you want it : `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this message: `'-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` it looks like users is not `NSArray`, its rather `NSDictionary`.

---

If you're not sure what is in JSON then check it before assigning to users:

```
id usersFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
if ([usersFromJSON isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    users = usersFromJSON;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Something wrong with my JSON: %@", usersFromJSON);
}
```

Comment: I need more code to tell you whats wrong exactly (except that you're calling `objectAtIndex` on dictionary) - post code where you're creating users.